# Add list at the end of another list (not just copy references)

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I can't just modify the original list.

This is how I've seen it done:

```
List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
l1.add("Hello");
l1.add("World");
List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>(l1); //A new arrayList.
l2.add("Everybody");
```

So I now would have a new list, which is a copy of the first one. And I can modify the second without the first being changed.

And now I'm having trouble understanding how to do the same, but adding the items at the end of the list.

What I though was doing exactly the above code, and adding the list to another list. With `addAll` for example. But I see everywhere how this only copies references and so on, so if it's inside a method or the its a rmi code the list itself wouldn't be complete, it'd get references to the other list I just created.

Since I need to do this for many types of list not sure if going item by item is ideal. So I need to add a list at the end of another list, if that's possible at all.

Comment: Which items do you want to add to which end of which list? Lists of Objects always only hold references, so you can only copy references from one List to another, if you use the constructor or adall for that doesnt matter

Comment: It copies references of the items that are added, not of the list. And this is also true for the method you have shown (with the `new ArrayList<String>(l1)`).

Comment: Copying references to immutable classes shouldn't be a problem. `String`s are immutable.

Comment: Java Lists hold references only.  it doesn't matter if you copy the object in the heap, the List will still only hold reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`addAll` copies references of the elements of the source list to the end of the target list, it doesn't copy a reference to the source list itself.

This is not different from what the constructor you are using - `new ArrayList<String>(l1)` - does. If one meets your requirements, the other does too.

BTW, in the case of a List of an immutable class, such as String, it doesn't matter that the references to the elements are copied (as opposed to copies of the elements), since you can't modify the elements, so nothing you can do to the content of the second list will affect the content of the original list.

Comment: Allright, didn't know that.

But that does mean that if I modify one list, I'm modifying both, right?

How do I avoid that? I want a copy of the list, at the end of a previously created one, if possible

Comment: @keont To put it simply. The `Objects` are referenced, not the `List`

Comment: @keont No, if you add or remove elements from one list, the other remains unchanged.

Comment: @keont As I explained in my edit, since your lists contain immutable objects (Strings), you don't need a copy of the elements. That would just be a waste of memory. You just need to copy the references to the elements, which both `addAll(l1)` and `new ArrayList<String>(l1)` do.

Comment: I see. I can't say I knew that at all. In my case I use a class I created as a generic for the list but I think the point still stands, so thanks for the help.

Just to be clear, addAll authomically adds at the end of the given list? I find that confusing, if it does so without anything else, but I guess it makes sense (and it's what I want anyway).

Comment: @keont Yes, addAll adds the elements of the source list to the end of the target list. Just like add does the same for a single element.

Comment: @keont If your list contains mutable objects, you may want to consider making a real copy, depending on your requirements. Consider this scenario : `List<MyObj> l1 = new ArrayList<>(); l1.add(new MyObj(4));List<MyObj> l2 = new ArrayList<>(l1); l2.get(0).setProperty(5);` Both lists contain the same single element. Therefore changing a property of the first element in `l2` from 4 to 5 changes that value of the same element in `l1`.

Comment: :( that's what I've been asking. So right now I believe in my case it wouldn't be an issue since the object is mutable but it's not goint to be changed, it's just going to be accessed, and I guess since I do not create a method to change it it can't be done.

That's what confuses me though, both lists are independent, since I can add elements to one of them and not affect the other one, but if I modify one of the elements, both end modified, correct?

Comment: @keont Correct. Both lists contain references to the same elements (that were originally in the first list). Therefore changing the state of one of these elements changes it in both lists. However, removing the reference from one list doesn't remove it from the other (since each list is a separate object).